# Spark File Streaming get File Names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, filestream

I need to know the fileName for the input file that is streamed from the input dir.

Below is the spark FileStreaming code in scala programming

```
object FileStreamExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

    val input_dir = "src/main/resources/stream_input"
    val ck = "src/main/resources/chkpoint_dir"

    //create stream from folder
    val fileStreamDf = sparkSession.readStream.csv(input_dir)

    def fileNames() = fileStreamDf.inputFiles.foreach(println(_))

    println("Streaming Started...\n")
    //fileNames() //even here it is throwing the same exception
    val query = fileStreamDf.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
      .option("checkpointLocation", ck)
      .start()

    fileNames();

    query.awaitTermination()

  }}
```

But facing the below exception, while streaming

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
FileSource[src/main/resources/stream_input]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `input_file_name()` function defined in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` to get the file name from which the rows are imported into the dataframe.

```
sparkSession.readStream.csv(input_dir).withColumn("FileName", input_file_name())
```

Comment: If we want size and last modified date of file, is anything available for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Databricks, please note in Databricks SQL and Databricks Runtime 13.1 and above input_file_name is deprecated. Please use `_metadata.file_name`.

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("csv") \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load("dbfs:/tmp/*") \
  .select("*", "_metadata")
```

https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html#language-python