# Logging HDFS file while read HDFS file using Spark readStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have written a small program that will continuesly read the incoming new files from a HDFS directory and will stream it to Kafka Topic.
While continuesly reading the HDFS file, I want to log these file into my logfile, but I am not finding any way to do it. And I also want to log the file once it is completely fed into Kafka topic. And while writting the data into Kafka topic I want to pass file name as header to kafka topic.

Below is the sample code I am using for read the file from HDFS and pushing it to Kafka Topic.

```
    StructType sch =  DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("cat", DataTypes.StringType, true)
    });

    Dataset<Row> jsonlines = spark.readStream().schema(sch).json("/data/json/") ;

    StreamingQuery query = jsonlines.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
            .writeStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint/topic2/")
            .option("batch.size", 10)
            .option("topic", "topic2").start();

    query.awaitTermination();
```

Can you please help, will really appretiate.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362352/spark-file-streaming-get-file-names . I think you can set kafka headers from structured streaming only in Spark3 (your dataframe should have a 'headers' column)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4953079/matthias-j-sax : Can you please help or give some pointers